# TypeError raised when using builtin "sorted" on JSON

Tags: python, json, list, python-3.x, sorting

Using Python 3.5, I'm running into a `TypeError` when I'm sorting JSON. The function can be found here on StackOverflow, and recursively sorts the dictionaries and lists found in valid JSON. I'm not using the json-module to sort my keys because it doesn't sort "deep" enough into the dictionary.

The `TypeError` arises from a comparison between two dictionaries: when similar dict's are evaluated by the builtin `sorted`, a comparison of their keys and values is made. If the keys are the same, their values are compared. If the values are of different types, a `TypeError` is raised.

Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "features": [{
        "attributes": {
            "AnalysisArea": 0.21410982
        }
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "AnalysisArea": null
        }
    }]
}
```

and here's the function:

```
def sort_json(iter_obj):
    if isinstance(iter_obj, dict):
        return sorted((k, sort_json(v)) for k, v in iter_obj.items())
    elif isinstance(iter_obj, list):
        return sorted(sort_json(x) for x in iter_obj)
    else:
        return iter_obj
```

My thoughts as to getting around this involve either a) casting None-type objects to a float or string (since the `TypeError` would also happen if None is compared to Str) or b) creating a custom class and overriding the `__lt__`, `__gt__` special methods to return `True` or `False` based on a type comparison. (e.g. if a=None and b=0.0, a

Is there a better way to avoid this issue and allow the sorted function to do my sorting for me without raising a `TypeError`?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?  How should "null" and a number be sorted relative to each other?

Comment: I'd like a much larger JSON to be sorted, but when this pattern is found, Python throws a TypeError.

Here's a sample: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByL968qEtAzBWnIxRlZKYWtQRjQ

Comment: Why are you trying to sort the values in the lists, the order **matters** in lists.  if you have a list of dictionaries how are you expecting the dictionaries to be sorted?

Comment: do you maybe want to use `collections.OrderedDict` so you still have a dictionary but the order of the keys is preserved?  If you do want to sort a list of dictionaries what logic would you sort by?

Comment: @Drew: I understand that.  My question is *what do you want the order to be*.  Suppose I give you a list like `[1, null, "hello"]`.  What do you think is the "correct" order that your sort function should return?

Comment: @BrenBarn It looks like None-type's cannot be sorted, so I'll have to figure out a new way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

[sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) allows you to specify the key function, and for Python3 there is a [functools.cmp_to_key()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) which lets you supply a comparison function (like you could in Python 2)

Write a comparison function that will sort it however you want it sorted.